# Exception not thrown in an async Task configuration

Tags: c#

I have the following method

```
    public async Task<bool> Connect()
    {
        lock (_connectingLock)
        {
            if (_connecting)
                throw new IOException("Already connecting");
            _connecting = true;
        }

        try {
             await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(...); 
        }           
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (_connectingLock)
            {
                _connecting = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I would expect consecutive calls to `Connect()` to throw an IOException, but it doesn't happen!

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calls to `Connect()` can't throw exceptions directly. Async methods *do not* throw exceptions. Instead, they will return tasks which, when awaited, will throw `IOException`. (i.e. the tasks are faulted.)

If that's not what you want, you should separate the calls:

```
public Task<bool> Connect()
{
    // Eager validation of state...
    lock (_connectingLock)
    {
        if (_connecting)
            throw new IOException("Already connecting");
        _connecting = true;
    }
    return ConnectImpl();
}

private async Task<bool> ConnectImpl()
{
    try {
         await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(...); 
    }           
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        lock (_connectingLock)
        {
            _connecting = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not clear whether that's appropriate in this case though. It's generally fine to throw things like `ArgumentException` eagerly, but if the error doesn't represent a bug in the calling code itself, I think returning a faulted task instead is fine.

Comment: Behold! NCrunch turned green. Cheers!

Comment: This case is also simple enough that you could implement it with just `ContinueWith`, and not `await`, so that the exceptions would need to be explicitly wrapped into the resulting task, rather than it happening implicitly.